# How to unsubscribe from valueChanges when using concatMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm reading [an article](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) about the rxjs `concatMap` operator. This guy builds an autosave form, i.e., whenever the user types a letter the data is saved using a http request

```
this.subscription = this.form.valueChanges
      .pipe(concatMap(formValue => this.http.put(`/api/course/${courseId}`, formValue)))
      .subscribe(saveResult =>  ... handle successful save ...);
```

I want to be able to unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()` from the `valueChanges` Observable, but the `this.subscription` Subscription refers to the `http` observable. So how can I unsubscribe from `valueChanges`?

Comment: If you call `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` any inner Observable inside `concatMap` is unsubscribed as well because this will dispose the whole chain.

Comment: So `valueChanges` will be unsubscribed, right? Can you give me a reference?

Comment: That's how RxJS works. See https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription/41177163#41177163

Answer (score 1):

In your ngOnDestroy function simply use your reference to the subscription.  When you create the observable it returns back a subscription object which exposes the `unsubscribe()` method.

```
ngOnDestroy{
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```